error 400 en url IPN woocommerce con mercadopago
Cómo están? Soy un usuario nuevo de woocommerce y mercadopago y estoy tratando de integrar mi tienda. Mi principal problema es que vendo suscripciones, cuando el usuario se suscribe sigue el proceso, paga en mercadopago, pero luego el pedido queda como en proceso en el woocommerce, por lo que el resultado final es que el usuario paga, pero no se le habilita la cuenta para que pueda acceder al contenido. Leyendo encontré que el problema está en que mercadopago no está notificando a woocommerce y entendí que lo que tengo que hacer es crear una URL IPN para que mercadopago notifique. Leyendo tutoriales encontré esta URL (que cargué en mi configuración de IPN dentro del plugin de mercadopago) xxxxdominioxxx.com/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_MercadoPago además de mi integrator ID. Hasta allí todo bien, pero cuando cargo la url de mercadopago me encuentro que tira error 400 bad request, tratando de diagnosticar el problema ejecuté curl -I a la URL de notificaciones y me sigue dando error 400:
HTTP/2 400
date: Wed, 07 Aug 2024 20:22:38 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-powered-by: PHP/8.0.30
expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
vary: Accept-Encoding
platform: hostinger
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
x-turbo-charged-by: LiteSpeed
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https://a.nel.cloudflare.com/report/v4?s=Znqwr5lxolacka14c7%2Bpl4HRIJ3x7o0ddSp1cm9VPCSTBC%2BdIQv1TEfYUwRYFaLweGSh9v7CyOHn7kzvvwiUKsc4qTBRZs%2FpJnZ%2Bwr5nAMHDoBynxKspHFmerL2p"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 8af9fadbcd2300e7-GRU
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
Allí empezaron las preguntas nuevas:

Esa url de IPN, debo crearla en algún otro lugar además de ponerla en la configuración del plugin? Al ingresar no da error de que no existe, si no que se ve "-1"
El problema será cloudflare?
El problema estará en que estoy usando https y no http?
Será que debo configurar otras variables en mercadopago y en el plugin para que mis usuarios puedan hacer todo el proceso automáticamente??

Mil gracias por la ayuda!
